# Nested monad binding in F#

Tags: f#, monads, f#+

Trying to wrap my mushy head around monads and binding

Take this snippet for example, purely as a learning excersise

```
open FSharpPlus
open FSharpPlus.Data

let lowerBounds i = 
    if i > 10 then
               Ok i
               else
                  Error "i was <= 10"

let upperBounds i = 
    if i < 20 then
                Ok i
                    else
                    Error "i was >= 20"
let even i = 
    if i % 2 = 0 then
               Ok i
              else
                  Error "i was uneven"

let rebind validation x = x >>= validation |> Seq.singleton

seq{10..20} |> Seq.map lowerBounds
    >>= rebind upperBounds
    >>= rebind even
```

Whilst this executes, I don't like the `rebind` function as it is not generic, and tied to `Seq.singleton`, not to mention I can't see how to make it point free (but that's a minor.....point)

Now I know I could pass in the dependencies, or totally refactor things and compose the validation functions, but I trying to learn how to bind to the nested monad. (Something like a recursive `>>=` infix operator ??) which feels like it would be the more FPish approach ?

As you can see I'm using FSharpPlus, and I had a look at the [monad transformer section](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpPlus/abstraction-monad.html) but I don't know even if that is what I should be looking at ?

Comment: Monad Transformers would solve the issue, but you don't need them in this example. You can compose the monadic functions and just map over the composition as shown in the answer. Otherwise you'll add unnecessary complexity to the problem.

Comment: Also note that you don't have nested bindings. All the bind operations you have in your code are over the Result monad, for `seq<_>` you are just mapping which is fine.

Comment: Still learning the terminology. In my example after the Seq.map I have a `Seq<Result<int,string>>`. I was trying to explore how to simply then "bind" the functions to that as a hypothetical.  Probably not the best example.

Comment: Well, if you need to bind a function that results in a `Seq<Result<_,_>>` then you can use a monad transformer, something like a `ResultT<Seq<_>>`. There are some examples in the Monad documentation http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpPlus/abstraction-monad.html#Examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Kleisli composition:

```
seq{10..20} |> Seq.map ( lowerBounds >=> upperBounds >=> even)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without composing the functions with the kesli operator ? I'm trying to understand a possible approach that "unwraps" the `Seq<Result<int,string>>` in order to bind the functions ?

Comment: @OrdinaryOrange not sure what you mean, provide an example.  if you don't want to use composition you would need to do a lot of nested matches: match lowerBounds i with
| Ok(i) -> match upperBounds i with
           | Ok (i) -> ....

Comment: Say the `lowerbounds` had already been mapped and I have a Seq<Result<int,string>>. I want then to use the `upperbounds` function. I cant `>>=` it nor `map` it directly as the `Seq<>` is the wrong type. I figure an approach was to somehow "unpack" the `Result<>` from the `Seq<>` to then bind that to the func. That is what my `rebind` function was doing. My poorly illustrated problem was an attempt to understand how to easily apply a function that needs one of the inner wrapped types. Does that help ?

Comment: seq{10..20} 
|> Seq.map ( lowerBounds >=> upperBounds )
|> Seq.map (Result.bind even)